# Draw area between two lines using Canvas on Android

Tags: android, graphics, canvas, statistics

I'm developing a simple statistical graphics class for my application. I've tried aChartEngine and others more, but I prefer use my own classes.
I'm drawing the graphics with the Canvas class that includes Android, but the problem is that I don't know how to fill the area between the line and the bottom  border.
Right now, the rectangles don't fill all the area, obviously, do You know any solution? Thanks a lot.

[image: This is my chart]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a [`Path`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html), with a [`Paint`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html) which has [`.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStyle(android.graphics.Paint.Style)) called.

```
Path fillPath = new Path();
fillPath.moveTo(0, 0); // Your origin point
fillPath.lineTo(x1, y1); // First point
// Repeat above line for all points on your line graph
fillPath.lineTo(xN, yN); // Final point
fillPath.lineTo(xN, 0); // Draw from final point to the axis ++
fillPath.lineTo(0, 0); // Same origin point
yourCanvas.drawPath(fillPath, /* Your paint */);
```

*++ Thanks to [@TheCapn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/804773/thecapn) for this bit.*

Comment: Just want to add that before your last "lineTo" call you should probably call something like `fillPath.lineTo(x,0);` so that the final line, if above the axis, does not cut back leaving an unfilled area.

Comment: @TheCapn Thanks, I've added that to the post. Good call on that one (I had, for some reason, assumed that `lastPoint.y` would be 0.)

Comment: are you not required to call `fillPath.close()` or what ever it is to end the line back to the start. Or is `lineTo` back to the point of start enough for `Path` to figure it out.

Comment: @Doomsknight I don't call `close()` in any of my code... it's probably a best practice but it's not necessary.