# Canvas fill color between two lines

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-view

I have two lines where one line is drawn at the same point every time and the other line is rotated by a certain degree every time the view is invalidated.

The code is as shown below :

```
 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            int centerx = width/2;
            int centery = height/2;
            canvas.drawLine(centerx, 0, centerx, height, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(0, centery, width, centery, paint);
            if (angle_in_degrees!= null)
                canvas.rotate(angle_in_degrees, centerx, centery);
            paint.setColor(0xff0000ff);
            canvas.drawLine(centerx, -1000, centerx, +1000, paint);
            canvas.drawLine(-1000, centery, 1000, centery, paint);
            paint.setColor(0xff00ff00);
        }
```

Everything works fine, but I want to fill the space between the two lines by a different color. How do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731406/draw-area-between-two-lines-using-canvas-on-android) sounds as if it would apply just as well to your situation. Essentially, the author uses a `Path` object to connect the dots between all points that need to be filled, before finally called `canvas.drawPath()` to fill the area inside.

In your case, this would probably look something like:

```
Path path = new Path();
path.lineTo(centerX, 0);
path.lineTo(centerX, height);
path.lineTo(0, centerY);
//etc. Essentially mirroring what your line does, but in one dimension (x,y) points.
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

**Edit:** You would also need to make sure the `Paint` object you use has a `FILL` style:

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply PPartisan. I did look at the link before but in my case I do not know the final point right?All I know is the angle at which the line should be rotated right? So how can I construct a path to my final point?

Comment: @shashank Can't say with certainty without testing, but I'd expect it to work in the same way it does for your line. (i.e. as the `canvas` has rotated, drawing a line between the two point is at an angle when restored). You may need to call `canvas.save()` before the rotation and `canvas.restore()` just before exiting `onDraw()` though.